# JSONP with native XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to make API call to twitch with callback.

https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?limit=25&offset=0&q=war&callback=responseReceived

Response I get is:

```
/**/responseReceived({"_total":959,"_links":   

{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?

 .....

  "}}}]})
```

Currently, I am doing weird thing like:

```
 callback(JSON.parse(xhr.response.split('responseReceived(')[1].split(")")[0]));
```

which is not right coz this might break for sure. I did google but only of 2 things come up

1. append script tag with src as api (which works but I want to see if I can use XMLHttpRequest())
2. jQuery (which i don't want)

Question:
1. in vanilla JS option 1 is the only way? or
2. any suggestions

[JSBin for ajax script](https://jsbin.com/biraja/edit?html)

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI you can use the `-` operator in a google search to remove a word from the search results, so try googling for `JSONP with native XMLHttpRequest -jquery`

Comment: that part of it, but not solve or answer the question.. Hope I am making sense? my question is not how to google how to make JSonp with native xMLHttpRequest

Comment: I know, this was just a comment to help you along.

Comment: oh ok,,, I am not sure why people gave -2?

Comment: Option 2 is really the same as option 1 here, it just means the script tag will be added by jQuery instead of by your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP is a JavaScript program and there is no good way to parse it. You either have to trust that it isn't going to vary the format or you have to execute third party code (the latter being how it is designed to be used, it's a relatively dangerous hack, which is why we now have CORS so we don't need JSONP). You could also write a complete JavaScript parser (in JavaScript!) and use it to find the function with the name that matches the callback, but that's rather non-trivial.

There is a third way though. If you remove `callback=...` from the URL then the service will return JSON instead of JSONP. Then you can just use `JSON.parse()` cleanly.

Comment: Hi Quentin, yes but i am trying to solve it with JSONP